# Tasty's Cookie Cream Puffs

Tags: baking

I saw some expert advice for someone's problems with Choux pastry posted here:
[Choux pastry (Chocolate eclairs) doesn't rise](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/choux-pastry-chocolate-eclairs-doesnt-cook-properly/9951#9951?newreg=4683fc57fa324e7ebf5c8fb8837dde80)

I'm having problems with this 'cheat' recipe here:

https://www.buzzfeed.com/alvinzhou/these-cookies-cream-puffs-will-sexually-awaken-your-taste-bu?utm_term=.xlKDknqB4&bffbtasty#.qbNRvWeOl

The choux uses:

- 1 cup water
- 8 tablespoons butter
- ½ cup flour
- ½ cup of crushed Oreo cookie crumbs.
- 4 eggs (one at a time)

Judging by the advice on the other thread, this recipe was very unlikely to work.  It there any advice on what needs to change to make it more viable?

While I can use the advice on the linked post to make normal Choux, I'm confused if I can just adjust it by dropping the flour for cookie crumbs?

Or is it easier to drop the cookie crumb recipe and simply substitute some flour for cocoa to make a chocolate choux case?

Comment: Dom, you can't adress a question to a single user, having the comunity chime in is the norm here. Take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more. This was flagged as "unclear, what you are asking" - please [edit] your post to clarify, more in our help: [ask]. And: welcome to Seasoned Advice!