# My éclair (pâte à choux) was doughy

Tags: baking, dessert

I followed the Pierre Hermé éclairs recipe:

> 60mL water
>    75mL whole milk
>    3g salt
>    3g caster sugar
>    56g butter
>    75g flour
>    A little over 2 eggs

I did the recipe and it called for 45 minutes of baking at 185°C.

I baked them for 40 minutes and left them in the oven for an extra 10 minutes before removing them.

The result was that the exterior was terrific, but the inside was too doughy and I couldn't fill it with crème pâtissière (custard).

Is skipping the 5 last minutes of baking the reason it failed?

Comment: Welcome to the site. "Doughy" as in uncooked, or something else?

Comment: it should be hollow from the inside right ? It wasn't. So when I fill it with cream, it pop to outside instead of filling the Chou.

Comment: Do you have a link to the recipe? How did you prepare it… exactly?

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong with the method, not with the oven

Comment: I got it from his book, pierre herme pastries.

Comment: I would suggest the last five minutes of cooking were important to help 'dry' out the interior.  Just try it again and see what happens.  Good luck!

Comment: It is not clear from the question itself, but from the "should be hollow in the inside right" comment it looks like your eclairs simply didn't rise. I am putting it on hold as a duplicate, whose answer is a very good troubleshooting list for eclairs. If I misunderstood you and you meant that they rose but something else happened on the inside, please edit in a more detailed explanation, and flag for reopening.

Comment: @rumtscho they rised properly but they still didn't dry enough from the inside

Comment: @droidnation OK, then we should reopen. How would you describe the interior? Was there no big hole to fill, despite them being larger than before baking? Or did the hole exist, but its walls were creamy instead of set? Something else?

Comment: They puffed normally to the desired size, but still not have big hole inside. Per example if I sliced them into half to put the cream, it will be like cutting  a piece of bread

Comment: Even if it's not a duplicate, you should check out [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/choux-pastry-chocolate-eclairs-doesnt-rise) cc @rumtscho

Comment: Leaving it in a hot oven an extra five minutes would, I think, counterbalance the lesser heat from having the oven shut off the last five minutes of baking.  A dish left in a hot oven does continue cooking in the residual heat, and I would not expect an oven to cool down enough so quickly (especially if unopened) to leave it under-cooked after forty minutes of baking.  I would guess there was some other problem, not the baking time.

Comment: Yeah. I think I didn't cook the dough enough after adding flour, when it forms the ball I remove from the heat and start adding the eggs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the last 5 minutes of baking would not have opened the texture of the interior.

Pâte à Choux is supposed to be very soft inside. It has ribbons of eggy material running through it. That is why cream puffs are usually scooped out before filling.

[image]

The material is very tender so, with eclairs, injecting the filling pushes it out of the way and the shell is firm enough to hold in the pressure.

When the dough is baking the steam inflates the abundant egg proteins in big pockets. This happens in the first part of baking and the rest of the time is setting the proteins and drying the exterior. If your interior truly has as tight a crumb as bread, this would have happened at the beginning of baking and the 5 minutes at the end would not affect it.

Pâte à Choux is very easy to make. I wonder about your process.
Recipes always consist of:

- Combine and scald, or boil, milk, butter, sugar, and salt,
- Add flour all at once and stir until it forms a cohesive ball that pulls away
  from the sides of the bowl,
- beat in the eggs one at a time.

I would make sure that your milk mixture was properly scalded and that your flour was mixed in well enough before adding the eggs. The flour should have gluten activated and its starches gelatinized before you add the eggs.

If you haven't been already, you might try using bread flour and see if the problem is lessened.

Comment: Thanks. Overall, testing is made key ingredient for success. It was the first time and I will repeat again.